# How to repeat a sequence in R but adjust values in the vector when repeated?

Tags: r, sequence, tidyverse, repeat

Here is an example:

This line of code repeats each subject specified twice:

```r
subject <- rep(c("maths", "english", "science"), each = 2)
```

So output in the console for "subject" is:

```r
# [1] "maths"   "maths"   "english" "english" "science" "science"
```

How can I adjust my code to make a minor change to the vector which is repeated? I would like the variable "subject" to produce the following when run:

```r
"maths.A" "maths.B" "english.A" "english.B" "science.A" "science.B"
```

This would be very useful when generating a lot of data. Entering the names manually would be very inefficient.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this, but any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```r
paste(rep(c("maths", "english", "science"), each = 2), c("A", "B"), sep = ".")
#> [1] "maths.A"   "maths.B"   "english.A" "english.B" "science.A" "science.B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try

```
with(expand.grid(c("A", "B"), c("maths", "english", "science")), paste0(Var2, ".", Var1))
```

Output

```
[1] "maths.A"   "maths.B"   "english.A" "english.B" "science.A" "science.B"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `sapply` or even `outer`:

```
c(sapply(c("maths", "english", "science"), paste, c("A","B"),sep="."))
[1] "maths.A"   "maths.B"   "english.A" "english.B" "science.A" "science.B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option

```
x <- c("maths", "english", "science")
y <- c("A","B")
do.call(paste,c(rev(expand.grid(y,x)),sep = "."))
```

which gives

```
> do.call(paste,c(rev(expand.grid(y,x)),sep = "."))
[1] "maths.A"   "maths.B"   "english.A" "english.B" "science.A" "science.B"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `outer`

```
c(outer(x, y, FUN = paste, sep="."))
```

#### data

```
x <- c("maths", "english", "science")
y <- c("A","B")
```